# $ρ_ωG$ is a subgroup of $ρG$ containing $G$.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

> The $G_δ$-closure of $A$ in space $X$ is defined as the set of all points $x ∈ X$ such that every $G_δ$-subset of $X$ containing $x$ has a non-empty intersection with $A$.

Now let $G$ be a topological group.The $G_δ$-closure of $G$ in the Rajkov completion $ρG$ of topological group $G$ will be denoted by $ρ_ωG$. Then why $ρ_ωG$ is a subgroup of $ρG$ ?

---

> For every topological Hausdorff group $G$ there exists a complete topological group $\rho G$ (the family of all minimal Cauchy filters on $G$) and a topological embedding $i : G\to \rho G$ ($i(x)=\beta_x$) such that $i(G)$ is dense in $\rho G$. Moreover, if $f : G\to H$ is a continuous homomorphism and $H$ is a complete topological group, then there is a unique continuous homomorphism $\hat{f} : \rho G\to H$ with $f = \hat{f}\circ i$. $(\rho G,i)$ is called  the Rajkov completion of topological group $G$.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what the Rajkov completion is?

Comment: @ShaneORourke: I added the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

Let $H$ be a topological group $H$ with an open base $\mathcal B$ at the unit and $G$ be a subgroup of the group $H$. Then $G_\delta$-closure of $G$ in $H$ coincides with the closure of $G$ in the topological group $H$ with a base $\mathcal B_\omega$ at the unit and therefore it is again a group, where 
$\mathcal B_\omega=\{\bigcap \{U_n\}_{n\in\omega}: \{U_n\}_{n\in\omega}$ is a sequence of elements of $\mathcal B \}$ (using Pontrjagin conditions for the family $\mathcal B$ it is easy to check that the family $\mathcal B_\omega$ satisfies Pontrjagin conditions too).

Comment: Pontrjagin conditions for the family $\beta$ are the conditions on family $\beta$ which implies that there exists a unique group topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $G$ such that $\beta$ coincides with the filter of all $\mathcal{T}$-neighborhoods of $e_G$ in $G$ ?

Comment: Specially In this case, 

 $i(G)$ is a subgroup of topological group $\rho G$. When we say that The $G_\delta$-closure of $G$ in the Rajkov completion $\rho G$, that is $G_\delta$-closure of $i(G)$ in $\rho G$ ?

Comment: @TXC For the description and properties of Pontrjagin conditions see, for instance, the first page of my paper “[Paratopological groups I](http://matstud.org.ua/texts/2001/16_1/37_48.pdf)”.

Comment: @TXC In your partial case we have that $H$ is the Raikov completion $\rho G$ of the group $G$ and the $G_\delta$ closure of the group $G$ should coincide with the closure of $G$ in the group $H$ endowed with the group topology with the base $\mathcal B_\omega$ at the unit.

Comment: Therefore, is it true that we can say that your answer as a little lemma: The $G_\delta$-closure of a subgroup $H$ of a topological group $G$ is a subgroup ?

Comment: @TXC My intuition says so, but, of course, this should be checked.